# What is model column in MigrationHistory table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In EF6 when you use Code First Migration, it creates a table that called `__MigrationHistory` with four column:

```
MigrationId
ContextKey
Model
ProductVersion
```

What is the binary data in `Model` field? Does it contain database schema? 
I mean if I have a database with hundreds of tables, does the `Model` field contain all of them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Internally it uses this function to get value for Model field:

```
    public virtual byte[] Compress(XDocument model)
    {
        DebugCheck.NotNull(model);

        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                model.Save(gzipStream);
            }

            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

So yes, it seems that the field contains whole model in a compressed form.

Comment: interesting, how do we get `XDocument model` from `DbContext` ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: it uses internal EdmxSerializer class to serialize object of type DbDatabaseMapping to XML format. DbDatabaseMapping contains all EDM information

Comment: @Masoud: the field contains whole model

Answer (score 24):

On MSSQL use

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(xml, DECOMPRESS(Model)) FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
```

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of **EF's migration** process understanding I would suggest checking **Max Vasilyev**'s enlightening [Inside of Entity Framework Migrations or How to View Generated Xml-Schema](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/) article .

The article provides a [sample project](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/?aid=878&sa=0).
You just need to save one of the sample outputs to **.edmx** file e open it using **Visual Studio**.